# Indicating a board move

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working on a game and I would like to indicate the move that was just made.

When the page loads I would like to indicate:

- Where the piece came from
- The new location
- The piece that use to be in the new location

I have tried, unsuccessfully, using  jquery fadein() and delay(). The following code represents the playing board. The top middle cell was the piece that was just moved to the top right cell, replacing the green piece. 
I have tried various ways to hide the newly moved (red) until the old (green) piece is faded away, but cannot figure it out.

Here is the current [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bLb3H/55/).

Thanks for any help.

```
<table border="1" id="tbl">
<tr>
  <td ></td>
  <td  bgcolor=#000000 >

 <img  src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/deleket/soft-scraps/32/Button-BlankRed-icon.png" id="fadeout1"/>        

  </td>
  <td id="cap" class="items  p1 p3 bg">

  <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/deleket/soft-scraps/32/Button-Blank-Green-icon.png" id="fadeout2"/>          

      <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/deleket/soft-scraps/32/Button-Blank-Red-icon.png"  /></td>      
 </tr>

 <tr>      
  <td bgcolor=#000000 ></td>
  <td class="items  p1"></td>
  <td class="items p3" bgcolor=#000000 ></td>
 </tr>

<tr>      
  <td class="piece" id="p1" ><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/deleket/soft-scraps/32/Button-Blank-Gray-icon.png" /></td>
  <td bgcolor=#000000 ></td>
    <td class="piece" id="p3" ><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/deleket/soft-scraps/32/Button-Blank-Gray-icon.png" /></td>
 </tr>

</table>
```

jquery:

```
 $("#fadeout1").show().delay(1000).fadeOut('slow')
 $("#fadeout2").show().delay(2000).fadeOut('slow')
```

Comment: Is this the effect you're after: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/bLb3H/56/?

Comment: could you set the new piece to display:none then use a fade out of the first piece and a fade in of the second (or am I missing the problem?)

Comment: This is great! Thank you j08691. I will try to implement this solution with the rest my code. Thanks.

Comment: Another quick question. Can you please alter your fiddle to show how to indicate if a piece moves to an empty space on the board? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/turiyag/bLb3H/57/

Instead of having the images not appear, just have them overlap, with position:absolute.

```
#tbl td { width:32px; height:32px; padding:0px; margin: 0px; vertical-align:top;}
img {position:absolute; padding:0px; margin: 0px;}
```

**EDIT:**

I'd recommend cleaning up your code as part of the troubleshooting process. Look into Refactoring (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring) for more info. My favorite text in this regard is (http://www.amazon.ca/Refactoring-Improving-Design-Existing-Code/dp/0201485672).

In your specific case, I would write more functions, and restructure your scripts to leverage the benefits of jQuery more heavily. Notably, I would include a function to draw the table, CSS classes to color the table, jQuery extensions to retrieve the x/y coordinates of cells in the table, and a function to determine the validity of moves. I've made an example of refactoring based on your code. You'll note that it is "self-documenting". From a simple glance it's easy to understand exactly what the code does, even without comments.

http://jsfiddle.net/turiyag/vCT9D/

```
$('#gameboard td').droppable({
    hoverClass: 'over',
    activate: function (event, ui) {
        isDragging = true;
    },
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        var img = ui.draggable;
        if($(this).validMove()) {
            movePiece(img, $(this));
            markValidMoves($(this));
        } else {
            img.draggable('option', 'revert', true);
        }
        isDragging = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much. It seems like a great solution. When I take this approach to the next step (http://jsfiddle.net/bLb3H/45/) I can't seem to drag the pieces. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Clearing up your code often does a lot for reducing errors and improving readability. Don't underestimate its power.

Comment: Thank you so much for the code and all the time you put in. I will look at the jquery and try to understand it. It's very helpful. Thanks.